# Siamese network with third component error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I was able to create a siamese network similar to :

https://github.com/aspamers/siamese/

The problem happens if I try to add a third model as an input to the head of my network.
I will get the following error :

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for '{{node head/concatenate/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](simple/Identity, simple_1/Identity, different/Identity, head/concatenate/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,?], [?,?], [?,?,1], [].
```

Here is the code below, one thing I am not comfortable with is the line processed_a = base_model1(input_a) and what it does even after checking the Keras model doc. I understand that if I don't do it I cannot have the desired shape and provide the necessary inputs to the final network.

Note that if I replace the code with what is comment and just use a pure siamese network it will work ok.
Any idea what needs to be changed to resolve the above error and what base_model1(input_a) does.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *

def getModel1(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    layer = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(model_input)
    layer = layers.Flatten()(layer)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs= layer, name="simple")

def getModel3(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(model_input)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=layer, name="different")

def outputModel(models):
    inputs = []
    for model in models:
        inputs.append(Input(shape=model.output_shape))
    layer = layers.Concatenate()(inputs)
    layer = layers.Dense(1)(layer)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer, name="head")

dataset = []
inputs1 = []
for i in range(0, 128):
    dataset.append([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
train_dataset1 = np.asarray(dataset)
base_model1 = getModel1(train_dataset1.shape)

dataset3 = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
train_dataset3 = np.asarray(dataset3)
base_model3 = getModel3(train_dataset3.shape)


input_a = Input(shape=base_model1.input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape=base_model1.input_shape)
input_c = Input(shape=base_model3.input_shape)

oModel = outputModel([base_model1, base_model1, base_model3])
#oModel = outputModel([base_model1, base_model1])

processed_a = base_model1(input_a)
processed_b = base_model1(input_b)
processed_c = base_model3(input_c)

head = oModel([processed_a, processed_b, processed_c])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b, input_c], outputs=head, name="model")
#head = oModel([processed_a, processed_b])
#model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=head, name="model")
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

model.predict([np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset3])])
#model.predict([np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset1])])
model.fit([np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset3])], np.asarray([1.0]), epochs=1000, validation_split=0, verbose=0, callbacks=[])
#model.fit([np.asarray([train_dataset1]), np.asarray([train_dataset1])], np.asarray([1.0]), epochs=1000, validation_split=0, verbose=0, callbacks=[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pay attention to the dimensionality that you define when u initialize the model input and output. the first dimension is always the batch size (None) and this can cause u some problem. here the correct example:

```
def getModel1(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(model_input)
    layer = Flatten()(layer)
    return Model(inputs=model_input, outputs= layer, name="simple")

def getModel3(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    layer = Dense(1, activation='relu')(model_input)
    return Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=layer, name="different")

def outputModel(models):
    inputs = []
    for model in models:
        inputs.append(Input(shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
    layer = Concatenate()(inputs)
    layer = Dense(1)(layer)
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer, name="head")

base_model1 = getModel1((128,3))
base_model3 = getModel3((3))

input_a = Input(shape=base_model1.input_shape[1:])
input_b = Input(shape=base_model1.input_shape[1:])
input_c = Input(shape=base_model3.input_shape[1:])

oModel = outputModel([base_model1, base_model1, base_model3])

processed_a = base_model1(input_a)
processed_b = base_model1(input_b)
processed_c = base_model3(input_c)

head = oModel([processed_a, processed_b, processed_c])
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b, input_c], outputs=head, name="model")

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

# create dummy data
n_sample = 5
train_dataset1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,128,3))
train_dataset3 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,3))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, n_sample)

model.fit([train_dataset1, train_dataset1, train_dataset3], y, epochs=3)
model.predict([train_dataset1, train_dataset1, train_dataset3]).shape
```

Comment: Hi Marco,thanks for the reply for base_model1 I want pictures as input thus the 128,3 dimensio, for model 2 it is just 3 single values

Comment: you mean base_model1 is (128,3) while base_model2 is (1,3) ?

Comment: I would think so, does it mean then doing base_model3 = getModel1((1,3,)) and base_model1 = getModel1((128,3,)) ?

Comment: Thanks let me try, can you also tell me what the line processed_a = base_model1(input_a) does?

Comment: It simply call/use the base_model1 for the input u pass, it's simpler than u can imagine

Comment: So it kind of creates another model for the specified input? I think it also somewhat modifies the base_model1, i was seing some error on the original code when oModel  was declared after processed_a

Comment: not create (u create before). it simply call/use the same model for every input u pass. in this way u can use the same weights for multiple inputs (that it's the correct way to initialize the initial siamese branches). does it work?